# WCF Data Services : add two new objects to the database with links between them

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, linq, wcf-data-services

I have these two tables in my database :

classes (*)<----------(1) teachers
-------                   --------

a teacher has many classes while a class only belongs to one teacher.

I do this in my wcf data services client :

```
            var teacher = new Teacher(1, "John");

            var class1 = new Class
                {
                    teacherId=teacher1.Id,
                    teacher=teacher1
                };

            teacher1.Classes.Add(class1);
            service.AddObject("Classes", class1);
            service.AddObject("Teachers", teacher1);
            service.AddLink(teacher1, "Classes", class1);
            service.SetLink(class1, "Teacher", teacher);

            service.SaveChanges();
```

I get the following exception when I execute :

> "The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint \"Teachers_Classes\". The conflict occurred in database \"MyDatabase\", table \"dbo.Teachers\", column 'TeacherId'.\r\nThe statement has been terminated."

Here is the Constraint defined in the table Classes :

```
 ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Classes]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT 
[Teachers_Classes] FOREIGN       KEY([Teachers_TeacherId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Teachers] ([TeacherID])
GO
```

Comment: The error seems to come from an issue with your DB configuration. How are the 2 tables defined? How are the foreign key constraints defined?

Comment: The Teacher table has a primary key TeacherId which is linked to Classes.TeacherId by a foreign key relationship.

Comment: Can you posted the SQL constraint definition of Teachers_Classes?

Comment: @dnikku, I've edited the question and added the constraint definition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution :

I had to pass in SaveChangesOption to the service.SaveChanges() method :

```
      service.SaveChanges(SaveChangesOptions.Batch);
```

Comment: Attilah, what is your email address. I have a similar issue but slightly different

Comment: when I do SaveChangesOptions.Batch the program cannot